# Extract multiple lines from text file

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, cisco

Source :

```
!
hostname RTR-1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
logging buffered 64000 informational
no logging console
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 description LAN
 ip address 172.16.29.250 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 172.18.1.130
 ip helper-address 172.18.1.127
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1350
 speed 100
 full-duplex
!
line vty 0 4
 exec-timeout 30 0
 transport input telnet ssh
 transport output telnet ssh
!
end
```

Output:

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip helper-address 172.18.1.130
 ip helper-address 172.18.1.127
```

Or:

```
!
hostname RTR-1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
logging buffered 64000 informational
no logging console
!
interface Vlan1
 description LAN
 ip address 172.16.29.250 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 172.18.1.130
 ip helper-address 172.18.1.127
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1350
 speed 100
 full-duplex
!
line vty 0 4
 exec-timeout 30 0
 transport input telnet ssh
 transport output telnet ssh
!
end
```

Output:

```
interface Vlan1
 ip helper-address 172.18.1.130
 ip helper-address 172.18.1.127
```

I exactly want to extract the name of interface in which command "helper-address" is configured.

The above source output is stored in file or can be extracted directly from live router

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. We are not a free script writing service and will not do your work for you. We will be happy to _help_ but you need to show us what you've tried and how it failed. Please see our [help center](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions for this site.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101596/using-python-to-parse-cisco-configuration-files-to-find-interfaces-with-specifi . If you can use python, ciscoconfparse seems like just what you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep "interface\|helper" source.file
```

Is the task so difficult to ask them here?

UPDATED:
If you are haven't `grep` in your OS you can substitute the script above by just shell-bultins:

```
while read
do
  case "$REPLY" in
  *interface*) echo "$REPLY" ;;
  *helper*) echo "$REPLY" ;;
  esac
done < source.file
```

Comment: I up your answer, however maybe required commend should be done in cisco's ...

Comment: @Archemar: in this case IMHO Mayur Patel's question is offtopic on "Unix & Linux".

Comment: All *nix systems, including embedded ones are [on topic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.